# Script to list the SQL Server Databases, Size and Utilisation by Specific Application or Service

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not sure if its possible, but would really appreciate any assistance.

I am looking for a script which can generate the complete list of SQL Server databases with the following details for each database of a SQL Server instance:

- Name
- Sizes
- Utilisation by specific application or service
- Hardware Utilisation (CPU, memory, I/O, etc.)

Comment: You might get a better answer on the DBA site, but I would seriously consider buying a tool that already does all this for you. There are plenty of monitoring solutions available for SQL Server.

Answer (score 22):

Using EXEC sp_databases may show the wrong sizes for the DB. Here's a nice, reliable query that will give all database names, sizes and statuses, although not which apps are utilising the DBs:

```
SELECT
    D.name,
    F.Name AS FileType,
    F.physical_name AS PhysicalFile,
    F.state_desc AS OnlineStatus,
    CAST((F.size*8)/1024 AS VARCHAR(26)) + ' MB' AS FileSize,
    CAST(F.size*8 AS VARCHAR(32)) + ' Bytes' as SizeInBytes
FROM 
    sys.master_files F
    INNER JOIN sys.databases D ON D.database_id = F.database_id
ORDER BY
    D.name
```

Comment: Shouldn't you divide by 1048576 instead of 1024 to get MB?

Comment: the text ' Bytes' should be ' KB', I think

Answer (score 6):

To get only general information (database name, files and size) you can have some success running the "sp_databases" stored procedure:

```
exec sp_databases
```

If the above didn't work in SQL Server 2000, you can try the following:

```
select *
from sys.sysdatabases
```

But you can get a more detailed trace and audit data using the "SQL Profiler" that is shipped with SQLServer.

Comment: Thanks, Jef! But I am looking to build a list of the current SQL Server utilization in terms of number of databases, their present sizes, utilisation by specific application or service, and location by server or cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Nagios](http://www.nagios.com/solutions/mssql-monitoring) for your various monitoring tasks. Nagios provides complete monitoring of MSSQL - including availability, database and table sizes, cache ratios, and other key metrics.

Comment: Thanks, David but I am not sure if we can have any monitoring tools beyond SCOM.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on the query above.

```
    SELECT
        D.Name as [Database Name],
        F.state_desc AS OnlineStatus,
        convert(varchar(12),CAST((sum(
        case when f.physical_name like '%ldf'then 0 else f.size end)*8.0)/1024.0/1024.0 AS numeric(8,2))) AS [Data File Size GB],
        convert(varchar(12),CAST((sum(
        case when f.physical_name like '%ldf'then f.size else 0 end)*8.0)/1024.0/1024.0 AS numeric(8,2))) AS [Log File Size GB]
        --,CAST(F.size*8 AS VARCHAR(32)) + ' Bytes' as SizeInBytes
    FROM 
        sys.master_files F
        INNER JOIN sys.databases D ON D.database_id = F.database_id
    group by D.name,F.state_desc
    ORDER BY
        D.name
```